# Matlab: What is the best way to keep trying and catching error such that the optimization process restart every time an error is seen?

Tags: matlab

I need run an optimization process using `fminunc` for 1000 times, which means I am essentially using a for-loop to loop the optimization process 1000 times. Sometimes, I will get an error like the following:

```
Error using fminusub (line 16) 
Objective function is undefined at initial point. Fminunc cannot continue.
```

or another error:

```
Error using chol
Matrix must be positive definite.
```

Now, it is obvious that these are two different type of errors and when either one of them occurs, the function will exit the for loop , which is painful for me to restart the entire process again. I am wondering whether it is possible to run a statement that try and catch **all the errors** and restart that single optimization process again **until it runs smoothly without encountering any errors**.

I just picked up matlab today and I have no idea how to do this ? Is this even possible ?

So far, this is what I have got in my mind:

```
try 

      % optimization process
      fminunc(.....)

       % if it fails
catch err
       % regenerate a new initial values then restart optimization process 
       initial_para = randn(1)
       fminunc(...., initial_para)
       % PROBLEM is: what if it fails again in the catch statement , how can I try and catch that 
end
```

Comment: I question: are the parts where the error may occur known?

Comment: Yes. How would you approach this problem ? I tried to write a while loop and within it, it has a try and catch statement. But it is not doing what I want it to do.

Comment: I think that I will need a little bit more information then. Something that you learn in programming course is that "There is no standard way to handle exceptions". The meaning with this is that the reason that an errors appear is always different and thus the solution need to be as well.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right.  I just added some pseudocode.

Comment: so you mean that you may get different kinds of errors inside the loop? In that case you need to find the id of the exception and an if statement inside the catch. You may also have one try-catch per error. Then add some checks that skips the code you know will fail. Eg `if ( length(y)>1 ), ...`

Comment: Ok I have edited the solution due to the code snippet. This will solve the problem presented.

Answer (score 1):

What is particular with this code is that the only difference between the try and the catch block is that you generate new initial parameters. So what you need to do in the catch is to solve the problem. And the problem is really that you have bad initial parameters, given the code in the question. This is what you have to solve. The way you solve this is really to use a while loop that goes on until it works. So instead of creating new initial parameters and repeat the same process as in try, you should use the code you have. Else you would be forced using recursion (I really would not use a recursion of try-catch! The debugging would be really painful). Ok, but what you do: Fix the problem in catch (which means set a new initial value) and repeat the process until it works.

```
success = false;
while (~success)
    try 
        % optimization process
        fminunc(.....);
        success = true;
    catch err
        % regenerate a new initial values then restart optimization process
        initial_para = randn(1);
    end 
end
```

So, the code will only reach `success=true` if the code in the try block works. Else it will go directly to the catch block.

Comment: This is not really what I want.Please see update of my question.

Comment: Why does the code exit the loop then? That seems weird if the try-catch block is inside the while loop.

Comment: Suppose the $i^{th}$ optimization process fails in the try block, the error is caught by the catch block and it restarts the $i^{th}$ optimization process again. If this also fails, then this will generate an error that will exit the for-loop. The key is that because it can still fail within the catch block

Comment: @mynameisJEFF Ok, then you must rethrow and catch the error in the next catch. Can it randomly fail many times inside the catch block?

Comment: @mynameisJEFF Ok, then it would be difficult. But why can you not just restart at the beginning of the loop and keep try catching until it works? Otherwise, if you know that a matrix that is not positively definite will fail, can you not do something like `while (det(A)~=0), %retry, end` or some other positive definite check?

Comment: Because the main problem is not aboutthe positive definiteness issue,  it is  more about the bad initial parameters.

Comment: So everytime it fails is it because of bad initial parameters? Are these set inside the while loop? This is why I say that every error is individual. you need to give me more background make sure to include **all** relevant code. I have no idea what causes the error or where it occurs. Because of that I cannot give you the help you need. You must give me the reason your error occurs. If I say "my car is not running", then you may ask "does it come smoke from the car". I may say not because I cannot even start the car. How are you supposed to know the key is broken? It is called the xy-problem

Comment: Yes, every time it failed it is because of the bad parameters. No they are set within the for-loop. I am not using a while loop, because in each iteration of the for-loop, I need to update something, which is irrelevant to the optimization process at this point.

Comment: @mynameisJEFF Can you please provide more information? This is complete incomprehensible, sorry. Maybe you should try to do the optimization outside the catch. Like `..., catch, success=false; %recovery, end, if (~success), try, %optimize; catch, %do something and go back to top of second try`